# Does using Ripper in Star Trek Discovery violate the prime directive?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, prime-directive

The Prime Directive is

> ...a guiding principle of the United Federation of Planets prohibiting the protagonists from interfering with the internal development of alien civilizations.

This is more about communicating with pre-warp societies.

In *Star Trek: Discovery* [S1:E5](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Choose_Your_Pain_(episode)) "Choose Your Pain", we hear:

> **Saru:** I have much to attend to, and I could use your help with one thing.
>
> **Burnham:** Of course.
>
> **Saru:** Dr. Culber believes the Tardigrade is sentient. It remains in a state of cryptobiosis. We have no claim on its soul. Go save its life, Burnham. That's an order.
>
> ([Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s01e05))

I'm trying to understand the ethical reasoning from a Star Trek perspective. Perhaps another directive applies.

My question is:

**Does using Ripper in *Star Trek: Discovery* violate the prime directive?**

Comment: I suppose this could also be Saru's own moral opinion.

Comment: You found a definition of the Prime Directive? You’ve done better than anyone else, then — as far as I know, it’s never actually been shown or quoted in any published Star Trek work.

Comment: thanks - that's helpful - I've updated the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It does not violate the Prime Directive, it is unethical for other reasons**

Not all ethics are part of the Prime Directive, indeed having a Prime Directive implies other Directives.

The tardigrade is an individual not a society, the ethics governing its use as a component are, as stated, because it is sentient. That is "able to perceive and feel things" it is not a non-sentient machine or or a biological mechanism. The applicable current ethic which would not have vanished from human/federation thought by the 23rd century is as follows:

The philosopher Immanuel Kant said that rational human beings should be treated as an end in themselves and not as a means to something else. A logical extension of this is is that even non-rational non-human sentient life should have the right not to be treated as 'things' ie non-sentient objects.

How much any rule or ethic however noble survives wartime expediency is partly what Star Trek Discovery is exploring.